# I want Javascript to run 3 seperate actions based on the filenames of open files in Photoshop

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

So I am currently trying to create a script in Javascript for Photoshop that will first prompt the user to point to a folder. From there it will open up all the files in that folder and then based on the names of the files it will run separate actions on those files with respect to which name they fall under.

Right now I am able to get all the files to open and have one action be executed on all of them. However I am having a hard time getting it to run different actions for different files.

Here is what the contents of each folder would look like.

(I want to have it select files named 1-18 or files that have less than 3 characters in their name.
1.psd
2.psd
...

...
18.psd

(for these I would have it select files that contain "-" in the name)

GHHJKK-1.psd 
GHHJKK-2.psd 
.....
GHHJKK-5.psd

(for these I would have it select files that contain the string "zoom")

zoom_side.psd

zoom_sole.psd

Here is what I have so far

```js
#target photoshop


var inputFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select a folder of documents to process");

function open360() {
  //app.open(File(openDialog()));
  
  var filesOpened = 0;
        var fileList = inputFolder.getFiles();
        for ( var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {
         open( fileList[i] );
         filesOpened++;
  
 } 
  
}
open360();


var doc = app.activeDocument;


 function shoeSFW() {
  
/* if (doc.filename.length < 3 ) {
  app.doAction("Zoom Side and Sole 360 SFW", "New SFW Actions");
  
 }
*/ 
 for(i = app.documents.length; i > 0; i--){
 
 if(app.documents.length != 0){ 

   doc = app.doAction("360 Shoes SFW", "New SFW Actions");
  } 
 }

}

shoeSFW();
```

I would really appreciate any help on this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {
        open(fileList[i]);
        filesOpened++;
        if(fileList[i].name.indexOf("zoom") != -1){ //contains "zoom"
            app.doAction("foo", "bar"); //first set of actions
        } else if(fileList[i].name.indexOf("-") != -1){ //contains "-"
            //second set of actions
        } else { //everything else
            //third set of actions
        }
}
```

Or, If trivial check for "zoom" and "-" won't be enough for you, you can use regexp.

Comment: thank you for the help, greatly appreciated. I will try this, I was able to figure out a different solution using the aspect ratio of the image but its nice to have this in the arsenal as well.